# What are the hotkeys to restart or shutdown Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, hotkeys

After running System Mechanic 12 registry maintenance, the computer froze on the info screen.
I tried to turn off the computer using the power button. This is a laptop, so disconnecting the power adaptor did not work. I want to try a hotkey, but I don't know how. I know that Ctrl-Alt-Del works on Windows 7.

Comment: A few more method you can try: Remove the laptop battery (if possible). Or press and hold the power button (5+ seconds) and usually it will forcefully shut it down. Ctrl-Alt-Del also works on Windows 8.

Comment: this question is so scary that couldn't figure out how to simply turn off a computer and require a hotkey to do so.

Answer (score 4):

Hold and press the power button for ~10sec.